# Multiple groupings at the same level

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I pull from three tables: A, B and C.

B and C reference A using a foreign key, so there is a 1-n relationship between A and B, and between A and C. Furthermore, there can be multiple matching records in A.  So the data could look something like this:

```
A(1) --> B(1), B(2), ... B(n)
       --> C(1), C(2), ... C(n)

A(2) --> B(1), B(2), B(3), ... B(n)
       --> C(1), C(2), C(3), ... C(n)
.
.
.
A (n) --> B(1), B(2), B(3), ... B(n)
       --> C(1), C(2), C(3), ... C(n)
```

I want records from A as the outermost group, then from B as inner groups at the same level, one after another.  So the report should look something like this:

```
Table A Record 1

  (Data distributed out into several rows)

  Table B Record 1
  Table B Record 2 ...
  Table B Record n

  Table C Record 1
  Table C Record 2 ...
  Table C Record n
```

Creating three groups will not work because they are always nested, so I cannot display B and C at the same level. (C will get nested inside B.) I cannot create 2 subreports for B and C because the entire thing is a subreport

How can I proceed?

Comment: Any reason you took 3 datasources instead using single source and joining tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join and union your tables and use groups on the second level that only print of needed.

```
TableA left outer join TableB
union all
TableA left outer join TableC
```

will result in records like

```
A(1), B(1)
A(1), B(2)
A(1), B(3)
A(1), C(1)
A(1), C(2)
A(2), B(1)
A(2), B(2)
A(2), C(1)
```

Create a your group for `B` and `C` on the same level and suppress them when no record is present (e.g. `B.Id is null`)

```
Group for A
    Group for B
    Group for C
```